# Coding in C: efficiency of temporary local variables

Tags: c, function, variables, coding-style

I was wondering: programming in C, let's say we have two functions:

```
int get_a_value();
int calculate_something(int number);
```

And two versions of a third one:

```
/* version 1 */
int main()
{
    int value = get_a_value();
    int result = calculate_something(value);
    return result;
}

/* version 2 */
int main()
{
    int result = calculate_something(get_a_value());
    return result;
}
```

Teorethically, what would be the difference between these two versions of the same thing, in terms of correctness, memory use and efficiency? Would they generate different instructions? On the other hand, what circumstances would make the possible differences significant in reality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any modern compiler compiler should produce the same code. Favor readability and let micro-optimizations be the job of the compiler.

Comment: Well... because I don't know how to check the assembler. You see, I am new in this. But help will be welcome in this point also.

Comment: I am interested in understanding how compilier does this work. Sorry if I am not literate in this... if I knew how to do it, I wouldn't ask. Constructive comments are more welcome than almost-rude ones. If you think I should ask it in a different way, you can say it kindly.

Comment: This question is relevant because of Martin Fowler's **refactoring** principle [Introduce Explaining Variable](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IntroduceExplainingVariable) aka [Extract Variable](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractVariable.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I performed a little test, generating assembler code for the 2 versions. Simply running a diff command from bash showed that the first version has 2 instructions more than the second one.
If you want to try by yourself simply compile with this command

```
gcc -S main.c -o asmout.s
gcc -S main2.c -o asmout2.s
```

and then check differences with

```
diff asmout.s asmout2.s
```

I got these 2 instructions more for the first one:

```
movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
```

EDIT:
As Keith Thompson suggested if compiled with optimization options the generated assembler code is the same for both versions.

Comment: You compiled with no optimization options, which is a way of telling the compiler you don't care about performance. When I compile with `gcc -O3 -S`, there's no difference at all.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. Can you think of a real situation where this difference is significant?

Comment: @KeithThompson You are right, running with optimization options leads to same result. For OP, I really think it is more a matter of which way it is more comfortable for you to write code rather than a performance problem.

Answer (score 3):

Copied both versions, compiled each with `gcc -S` to get the machine language output, used `sdiff` to compare side-by-side.

Results using gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux):

No optimization:

```
main:                                         main:
.LFB2:                                        .LFB2:
        pushq   %rbp                                  pushq   %rbp
.LCFI0:                                       .LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp                            movq    %rsp, %rbp
.LCFI1:                                       .LCFI1:
        subq    $16, %rsp                             subq    $16, %rsp
.LCFI2:                                       .LCFI2:
        movl    $0, %eax                              movl    $0, %eax
        call    get_a_value                           call    get_a_value
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)              |         movl    %eax, %edi
        movl    -8(%rbp), %edi              <
        movl    $0, %eax                              movl    $0, %eax
        call    calculate_something                   call    calculate_something
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)                        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax                        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        leave                                         leave
        ret                                           ret
```

Basically, one extra move instruction.  Both allocate the same amount of stack space (`subq $16, %rsp` reserves 16 bytes for the stack), so memory-wise there's no difference.

Level 1 optimization (-O1):

```
main:                                       main:
.LFB2:                                      .LFB2:
        subq    $8, %rsp                              subq    $8, %rsp
.LCFI0:                                     .LCFI0:
        movl    $0, %eax                              movl    $0, %eax
        call    get_a_value                           call    get_a_value
        movl    %eax, %edi                            movl    %eax, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax                              movl    $0, %eax
        call    calculate_something                   call    calculate_something
        addq    $8, %rsp                              addq    $8, %rsp
        ret                                           ret
```

No differences.

Results using gcc version 2.96 20000731 (Red Hat Linux 7.2 2.96-112.7.2):

No optimization:

```
main:                                         main:
        pushl   %ebp                                  pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp                            movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp                              subl    $8, %esp
                                             >        subl    $12, %esp
                                             >        subl    $4, %esp
        call    get_a_value                           call    get_a_value
                                             >        addl    $4, %esp
        movl    %eax, %eax                            movl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)               |        pushl   %eax
        subl    $12, %esp                    <
        pushl   -4(%ebp)                     <
        call    calculate_something                   call    calculate_something
        addl    $16, %esp                             addl    $16, %esp
        movl    %eax, %eax                            movl    %eax, %eax
        movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)               |        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax               |        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %eax                            movl    %eax, %eax
        leave                                         leave
        ret                                           ret
```

Roughly the same number of instructions, ordered slightly differently.

Level 1 optimization (-O1):

```
main:                                         main:
        pushl   %ebp                                    pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp                              movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp                      |         subl    $24, %esp
        call    get_a_value                             call    get_a_value
        subl    $12, %esp                     |         movl    %eax, (%esp)
        pushl   %eax                          <
        call    calculate_something                     call    calculate_something
        leave                                           leave
        ret                                             ret
```

Looks like the second version reserves a little more stack space.

So, for this particular example with these particular compilers, there's no huge difference between the two versions.  In that case, I'd favor the first version for the following reasons:

1. Easier to trace in a debugger; you can examine the value returned from `get_a_value` before passing it to `calculate_something`;
2. It gives you a place to do some sanity checking, in case `calculate_something` isn't well-behaved for certain inputs;
3. It's a little easier on the eyes.

Just remember that *terse* doesn't necessarily mean *fast* or *efficient*, and what's fast/efficient under one particular compiler/hardware combination may be hopelessly busted under a different compiler/hardware combination. Some compilers actually have an easier time optimizing code that's written in a clear manner.

Your code should be, in order:

1. Correct - it *doesn't matter* how fast it is or how little memory it uses if it doesn't meet its requirements;
2. Secure - it *doesn't matter* how fast it is or how little memory it uses if it's a malware vector or risks exposing sensitive data to unauthorized parties (yes, I'm talking about Heart-frickin'-bleed);
3. Robust - it *doesn't mattter* how fast it is or how little memory it uses if it dumps core because somebody sneezed in a different room;
4. Maintainable - it *doesn't matter* how fast it is or how little memory it uses if it has to be scrapped and rewritten because the requirements changed (which they do);
5. Efficient - *now* you can start worrying about performance and efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the platform and the compiler, but with optimization on they should usually generate the same code. At worst version one will allocate space for an extra int. If placing the value of get_a_value in a variable makes your code more readable then I would go ahead and do that. The only time I would advise not doing so is in a deeply recursive function.